# How to scroll only one cell In UICollectionview while swiping the Cell?

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am displaying the 3 cells at the same time in `UICollectionView`. How to force the user to horizontally scroll only one item at a time in `UICollectionView`?

Answer (score 4):

This should be enough:

```
self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Swift version:

```
self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = true
```

Comment: If the OP is displaying three items at a time, this will scroll through three items at a time, not one.

Answer (score -2):

If you want your cells to be moved only one at a time then you need to set the frame of cell equals to the collection view and then set the collectionView's paging enabled as below,

```
[collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

or

```
collectionView.pagingEnabled=YES;
```